# Mysql <= is giving the wrong output

Tags: mysql, database

My table

```
starttime   |   endtime  |   id

10:30            11:30        1
11:30            12:30        2
14:30            16:30        3
15:30            16:30        4
```

If I wanted to select the id's between 10:30 to 12:30 I use this below command

```
select id
from table
where STR_TO_DATE(starttime,'%H:%i')>='10:30' and
      STR_TO_DATE(endtime,'%H:%i')<='12:30';
```

This gives me only id 1 ,but not giving me 2 and If i change 12:30 to 12:40 it gives me 1 & 2.BUt I am using less or equal so it should give me both the id's right? Why its not working like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to compare a date object against a string.  To be precise, in the following expression

```
STR_TO_DATE(starttime,'%H:%i') >= '10:30'
```

`STR_TO_DATE` returns a date, but `'10:30'` is just a varchar (which coincidentally looks like a time).  If you want to continue down this road, you should cast both sides of the comparison using `STR_TO_DATE`:

```
SELECT id
FROM table
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(starttime,'%H:%i') >= STR_TO_DATE('10:30','%H:%i') AND
      STR_TO_DATE(endtime,'%H:%i') <= STR_TO_DATE('12:30','%H:%i');
```

But a long term better approach would be to make your `starttime` and `endtime` columns either `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`.

## SQLFiddle

Comment: One more problem suppose there is a entry on table which covers two hours like 11:30 to 13:30 in this situation when I try run a query with
STR_TO_DATE(starttime,'%H:%i') >= STR_TO_DATE('12:30','%H:%i') AND
      STR_TO_DATE(endtime,'%H:%i') <= STR_TO_DATE('13:30','%H:%i');

it gives empty set :(

Comment: @RajaDhasan Look closely at your data; there are no records where the start time is `>= 12:30` and the end time is `<= 13:30`.

Comment: NO no see my comment above. Ok for example I have an entry with id=5 starttime=11:30 and endtime=13:30 (Assume other entries have been removed)
Now  when I check for time range in between 10:30 to 12:30 it should return the above entry but it fails to do so

Comment: No.  Upon adding `id=5` per your comments the query only should return the first record with `id=1`, see my Fiddle.